# Intuition about the gradient of the constraint

Tags: intuition, gradient, constraint

I was rethinking the logic of solving constraint optimization problem. And I read many stuff in website like this and textbooks. But the following question is still unsolved (to me).

We know that at a local extreme point, the gradient of the objective function $f$ and the gradient of the constraint function $g$ is aligned. Many study materials have draw pictures to illustrate this idea and also many excellent textbooks have derived this algebraically. However, all these to me is that "$\nabla f = \lambda\nabla g$ HAPPENS to be true when you have a local extreme".

The logic for considering $\nabla g$ is not clear to me. I was thinking the constraint $g(x)=0$ is fixed, hence you can only move on this curve $g(x)=0$, then what's the point of considering the gradient of function $g(x)$ pretending that AS IF we can move to "another constraint $g(x)=c$".

Comment: The intuitive idea is that there is no component of grad f not aligned with grad G,  otherwise you could go in that direction without changing the constraint (and it would not be a minimum)

Comment: "otherwise you could go in that direction without changing the constraint", which direction you mean?$\nabla f$? or $\nabla g$? why if you go that direction, then constraint is still satisfied?